# What is the exact equivalent of JS: something.toFixed() in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

If I have  `a.toFixed(3);` in javascript ('a' being equal to 2.4232) what is the exact equivalent command in php to retrieve that? I searched for it but found no proper explanation appended to the answers.

Comment: I think PHPs `round()` is going to be as close as you get out of the box...http://php.net/round

Comment: Aside from `sprintf` `number_format` is the closest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found that `sprintf` and `number_format` both round the number, so i used this:

```
$number = 2.4232;
$decimals = 3;
$expo = pow(10,$decimals);
$number = intval($number*$expo)/$expo; //  = 2423/100
```

Answer (score 45):

The exact equivalent command in PHP is function [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
number_format($a, 3, '.', ""); // 2.423
```

- it rounds the number to the third decimal place
- it fills with '0' characters if needed to always have three decimal digits

Here is a practical function:

```
function toFixed($number, $decimals) {
  return number_format($number, $decimals, '.', "");
}

toFixed($a, 3); // 2.423
```

Comment: Note: `number_format` returns string not float or int which could make some errors in some cases.

Answer (score 26):

Have you tried this:

```
round(2.4232, 2);
```

This would give you an answer of 2.42.

More information can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: In case of using it for round(2.4255, 2) it would return 2.43

Comment: @DănuțMihaiFlorian It depends on what you've set as `mode` http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php#refsect1-function.round-parameters

Comment: In case of 64.000000, it returns 64. I would like to get 64.00

Comment: @NalinAgrawal: You may have to cast it to a double to get that, though it seems that you might be wanting that for displaying on a page, in which case there are string formatters that will maintain certain decimal precision, though that's more string-related than numerical-related.

Answer (score 4):

A direct equivalent is `sprintf('%.03F', $a)`. This will format the value in question as a number with 3 decimal digits. It will also round if required.

Comment: tested. does not round.

Answer (score 2):

The straight forward solution is to use in php is `number_format()`

```
number_format(2.4232, 3);
```

Comment: How is this different from @cassiodoroVicinetti's answer from Aug 28 '14 at 19:15 (4 1/2 **years** ago)?

Comment: this one is straight forward

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can use a function called [round](http://php.net/round).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the translation:

```
function toFixed($number, $dec_length){
    $pos=strpos($number.'', ".");
    if($pos>0){
        $int_str=substr($number,0,$pos);
        $dec_str=substr($number, $pos+1);
        if(strlen($dec_str)>$dec_length){
            return $int_str.($dec_length>0?'.':'').substr($dec_str, 0,$dec_length);
        }else{
            return $number;
        }
    }else{
        return $number;
    }
}


//toFixed(1234.678, 0) = 1234
//toFixed(1234.678, 1) = 1234.6
//toFixed(1234.678, 2) = 1234.67
//toFixed(1234.678, 4) = 1234.678
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```php
    function to_fixed($number, $decimals) {
        return floatval(number_format($number, $decimals, '.', ""));
    }
```

call it like this

```php
to_fixed(2.4232, 3); //  2.423
```