# How to get different float precisions for different fields when serializing JSON?

Tags: php

How can I get for example:

```
{"latitude": 35.123000,"longitude": 41.123500,"height": 100.00}
```

Instead of:

```
{"latitude": 35.123,"longitude": 41.1235,"height": 100}
```

I get this output with the following code:

```
ini_set('serialize_precision', 6);
...
// calculate latitude, longitude and height
...
$response->payload->latitude = rad2deg($latitude);
$response->payload->longitude = rad2deg($longitude);
$response->payload->height = $height;
// some other fields in response..

print(json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

I also tried using `(float)number_format(...)` but could not get what I want.

Comment: I personally do understand how to make a more precise number less precise, but vice-versa?

Comment: The downvote is here because it's unclear what you're asking about. `serialize_precision` is about significant digits (not zeros).

Comment: If all you want is keep extra zeros then the question is absolutely basic.

Comment: I know, but I have to come up with what I've tried right? I wouldn't be asking if I knew what to use instead.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670114/what-is-the-exact-equivalent-of-js-something-tofixed-in-php

Comment: That's not a duplicate, nobody has to know JavaScript's .toFixed to find a php solution.

Comment: your post is duplicate not because of how the linked question is formulated, but because it has an answer to your question

Comment: Formatting a float to have less precision is just that, _formatting_. And formatting is for _human eyes_, not data serialization and transfer. Abandon the notion of making JSON pretty to look at, and format the data for display only when you are _about to display it_.

Answer (score -1):

You should run your values through [`number_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

```
$response->payload->latitude = number_format(rad2deg($latitude), 8);
$response->payload->longitude = number_format(rad2deg($longitude), 8);
$response->payload->height = number_format($height, 2);
```

Output:

```
{
    "latitude": "35.12266800",
    "longitude": "41.12348100",
    "height": "100.00"
}
```

Keep in mind that this will convert your floats into strings.

Comment: I downvoted because it's clearly a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670114/what-is-the-exact-equivalent-of-js-something-tofixed-in-php) and such questions should be closed, not answered

Comment: Hi, I'm not the downvoter. I avoid outputting numeric values as string. This is why in the question, I said I tried casting `number_format` to float

Comment: @nomore numbers with trailing excess zeros don't exist, they're not numbers. It's the only solution to the problem.

Comment: As far as the PHP interpreter is concerned. `35.123 === 35.12300000`. The only difference is how they are displayed, which you can control with `number_format`. Storing the value with trailing zeros only uses up extra bytes on the filesystem. Instead of writing the formatted values into your json file you should format the stored floats at output time.